# Does Realm have size limitation over one column of a table

Tags: android, sqlite, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am working on Realm database for android. My requirement is I need to store large data (more than 2mb minimum) in a single column of a row in a table. In normal SQLite - android we can not fetch the data from column table if is has more than 2mb size(due to the cursor window size limitation). So I want to move from sqlite to realm. But when I do a sample app which stores and retrieves more than 2mb, Realm also throws exception.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 46633948 byte
>   allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 39MB until OOM
>                                                                        at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
>                                                                        at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)
>                                                                        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)

Which is the best way? I don't have any choice to split the data and storing it in the file and file path store in db. I need to store large data (String in encrypted format) in a single column.

Comment: post error log here

Comment: Please my edit for the question

Comment: did you try `largeheap=true`

Comment: Realm supports a max 16 MB column size.

Comment: As pointed out Realm will support up to 16 MB pr. field, but your app might still OOM if it doesn't have enough memory to read it, which looks like what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

From https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#limitations-general

> Strings and byte arrays (byte[]) cannot be larger than 16 MB.